# Use of this space of very rapidly decreasing continuous functions

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ct.category-theory, banach-spaces, definitions

Let $C_n$ denote the subspace of continuous function on $[0,\infty)$ supported on $[n,n+1]$.  Denote the $\ell^p$-direct sum Banach space 
$$
V_p
:= 
\left\{
f \in C([0,\infty)):\,
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(
\sup_{x \in [n,n+1] } |f(x)|
\right)^p <\infty
\right\}.
$$

In the case where $p=\infty$ we regain the space of function vanishing at infinity but what about $p<\infty$?  Are these spaces studied?  If so what are their use?

Comment: The notation in your first line is extremely confusing. $C([n,n+1])$ should mean, and can only mean, the continuous functions on $[n,n+1]$. You then seem to switch to functions defined on $[-n,n]$

Comment: I think it would be much clearer to avoid the notation on the LHS and just define your Banach space $V_p$ to be the space on the RHS. Then $V_p$ embeds isometrically inside the $\ell_p$-sum of copies of $C[0,1]$, as a complemented subspace

Comment: What's the other summand then and is this object useful?

Comment: If I understand the definitions correctly, $V_p$ is the kernel of the map $Q:\left(\bigoplus_{n=0}^\infty\right)_{\ell_p} C[0,1] \to \ell_p$ defined by $Q((f_n)_{n=0}^\infty) = (f_{n}(0)-f_{n-1}(1))_{n=1}^\infty$. In other words, you're just taking an equalizer of a bunch of a functionals, expressing the idea that a continuous bounded function on $[0,\infty)$ is obtained by gluing together a sequence of functions on $[0,1]$ which "match up" at the endpoints

Comment: It is clear that $Q$ has an isometric right inverse, and so the kernel of $Q$ is complemented. As to whether this object is useful: there are, in some sense, uncountably many Banach spaces that one could define, so the question is whether **you** have something you want to do with this space, either in terms of theorems or in using the space as a natural home for particular functions arising in e.g. probability or ODE

Comment: Thanks Yemon.  This is basically what I needed from an answer.  If you'd like to post exactly this it I'd accept it gladly.