# Comparison of inductive limit topology with very-rapidly decaying non-convex $L^{!/2}$-space topology

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ct.category-theory, banach-spaces, integration, limits-and-colimits

This is related to [these posts](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/358663/use-of-this-space-of-very-rapidly-decreasing-continuous-functions) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/347318/can-l1-loc-be-represented-as-colimit).

Let $L^1([n,n+1])$ denote the subspace of $L^p$-functions on $[0,\infty)$ essentially supported on $[-n,n]$.  Denote the accelerated $\ell^1$-direct sum Banach space 
$$
\bigoplus_{n \in \mathbb{N}}^{\ell^1} L^{1/2}([0,n])
:= 
\left\{
f \in L^{1}([0,\infty)):\,
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(
2^n\int_{x \in [n,n+1] } \sqrt{|f(x)|} dx
\right) <\infty
\right\}.
$$

Alternatively, equip $L^1_{\mathrm{comp}}$ be the space of essentially compactly-supported $L^p$ functions, with their usual inductive limit topology obtained by the inductive system
$$
\left\{f \in L^1_{\mathrm{loc}}: \, 
\operatorname{esssupp}(f)\subseteq [0,n]
\right\}
\to
\left\{f \in L^1_{\mathrm{loc}}: \, 
\operatorname{esssupp}(f)\subseteq [0,m]
\right\}\qquad n\leq m;\, n,m \in \mathbb{N}
,
$$
in the category of topological vector spaces.  Is the topology of $\oplus^{\ell^1}_{n}L^1([0,n])$ coarser than that of $L^p_{\mathrm{comp}}$ on their intersection?

It seems to me to be the case since $\oplus^{\ell^1}_{n}L^1([0,n])$ is much smaller than $L^p_{\mathrm{comp}}$.

Comment: Just as a general point, your space is just equal to $L^{1/2}([0,\infty))$ when you change measure to $\nu$, defined by the Radon-Nikodym derivative $\frac{d\nu}{dm}(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{2^n} I_{[n,n+1]}(x)$ (here $m$ is the Lebesgue measure).